# Defining reset slectors for memoization across multiple component instances

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reselect

I am looking to using the redux `reselect` lib to write my react-redux selectors. From the docs there is [this section](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#sharing-selectors-with-props-across-multiple-component-instances) [that](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#sharing-selectors-with-props-across-multiple-component-instances) describes how to write selectors that can be used by several component instances.

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { toggleTodo } from '../actions'
import TodoList from '../components/TodoList'
import { makeGetVisibleTodos } from '../selectors'

const makeMapStateToProps = () => {
  const getVisibleTodos = makeGetVisibleTodos() // here
  const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    return {
      todos: getVisibleTodos(state, props)
    }
  }
  return mapStateToProps
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: (id) => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
    }
  }
}

const VisibleTodoList = connect(
  makeMapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList)

export default VisibleTodoList
```

I am wondering if the differences in how the makeGetVisibleTodos selector is called(as shown below), has implications on how memoization works. will memoization still work?, if not, why?

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { toggleTodo } from '../actions'
import TodoList from '../components/TodoList'
import { makeGetVisibleTodos } from '../selectors'

const makeMapStateToProps = () => {
  const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    return {
      todos: makeGetVisibleTodos()(state, props) // and here
    }
  }
  return mapStateToProps
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: (id) => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
    }
  }
}

const VisibleTodoList = connect(
  makeMapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList)

export default VisibleTodoList
```

Comment: An interesting question for sure. And then this: "_will it still work?, if not, why?_" - you have all the code, it seems you would have everything you need to answer your own question. What am I missing?

Comment: sorry, probably a language limitation I meant to ask if the memoization part itself will work, not the code. @RandyCasburn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That example will never memoize at all, because it's creating a new selector instance every time `mapState` runs.

The key to correctly using memoized selectors is:

- Reuse the same selector instance multiple times
- And keep passing it the same arguments

If you create a new selector instance, it has no cached values.  If you have the same instance but pass it *different* values each time you call it, then the memoization never works.

For more details, see my post [Using Reselect Selectors for Encapsulation and Performance](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/12/idiomatic-redux-using-reselect-selectors/).